# TimeSpan overflowed because the duration is too long

Tags: c#, timespan

I just received an error on my application that I have never seen before.  Any chance anyone knows what this means explicitly?  I understand the timespan duration was too big, but what are the actual numbers that make it too long?

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) shows there's a property '[MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)' that contains the largest possible value. It also explains what that value is in english.

> The value of this field is equivalent to Int64.MaxValue ticks. The string representation of this value is positive 10675199.02:48:05.4775807, or slightly more than 10,675,199 days.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe, you are creating a TimeSpan from a formula in wich you are doing a division by zero.

```
var variable1 = 1000;
var variable2 = 0;
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(variable1/variable2);
```

This will throw an "TimeSpan overflowed because the duration is too long." exception

Comment: Just wanted to point out this was my issue and I have a feeling that most people that google this exception are having the same issue since otherwise the exception is pretty well-named (if you try to put a big number into a TimeSpan you probably wouldn't have to google the problem).

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for The `TimeSpan.MaxValue` which is the maximum number of ticks the TimeSpan can store, which is `long.MaxValue` which is 9223372036854775807